# why scrapy won't load any of my pipelines?

Tags: windows, scrapy, python-3.7

ok, so Im using `Scrapy` for some basic web scraping and its working fine on scraping part! when get some output using feed export something like `-o output.csv` wont do anything, it will make an empty file but nothing else.

after a period of confusion I couldn't  make it work so i've decided to use a pipeline to write some custom method of exporting. but now the problem is even though the application is working fine... its just not load the pipelines. not any single one of them is not running and there is no error.

this is my settings.py where I put the option to load them:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'fbcrawl.pipelines.CsvExporterPipeline': 300
}
```

and this is my `CsvExporterPipeline` class inside `pipelines.py`:

```
class CsvExporterPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print('\n' * 2)
        print(item)
        print('\n' * 2)
        return item
```

and its not gonna run neither of these 3 prints wont run at all.

I want to know how can I have my pipelines loaded and working?

UPDATE: i forgot to mention that im trying to run this code... so the spider is mentioned here:

https://github.com/rugantio/fbcrawl

Comment: check for proper path to your pipeline - try to import this inside settings. I think you should go with path like this: `'fbcrawl.fbcrawl.pipelines.CsvExporterPipeline'`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `BOT_NAME` in `settings.py` is set at `fbcrawl` ?

And what is the code of your spider ?

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes thats exactly what is written in settings.py. I updated the question with the code repository im trying to run. you can see the spider in that link. its a little bit long so its better to read it in the git hub repo.

Comment: In `fbcrawl.py` the only method which return an item is `parse_reactions(self,response)`, check if the spider enter this method or not.

Comment: so basically there should be a return in spider methods and its not gonna load pipelines if i use yield for multiprocessing stuf?